# Problemas con editButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c

Tengo una pregunta. Coloco un botón en objective C, `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem`. Me muestra el botón pero no me actúa. Lo tenía montado en un `TableViewController` y lo he pasado a un `ViewController` y me ha dejado de funcionar. Estoy un poco perdido.

Comment: Intenta pasando el metodo que lanza la acción del botón del TableViewController al nuevo controller, ¿el boton esta agregado por StoryBoard?.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la clase `TableViewController` tiene una propiedad `editButtonItem`. Mientras que la clase `ViewController` no la tiene